# Como puedo guardar el tokenJWT que me retorna AXIOS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, axios

Tengo el siguiente código y estoy haciendo la petición desde la librería de AXIOS node.js

```
const axios = require('axios');


const loginAPI =  async () => {
    const data = JSON.stringify({
        "username": user_agent,
        "password": pass_agent
    });

    const config = {
        method: 'post',
        url: url_api+'/login',
        headers: { 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data : data
    };

    axios(config).then(function (response) {
        const resp = JSON.stringify(response.data.response) // quiero almacenar este token y poderlo utilizar en cualquier otra función
        console.log(resp); 
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}


console.log(loginAPI());


loginAPI();
```

ejemplo: quiero pasar el token de la función anterior a esta nueva:
para que en 'Authorization' pase el token de manera dinámica proveniente de la función login y no estar copiando y pegando.

```
const seession = () => {
    var config = {
        method: 'get',
        url: url_api+'/session',
        headers: { 
            'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL3BhcnRuZXJzLWFwaS1kZXYud2luZ28uY29tIiwic3YXV0aC1qd3RAd2luZ28tcWEtMjE0NDE2LmlhbS5nc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQuY29tIiwiaXNzIjoiYXV0aC1qd3RAd2luZ28tcWEtMjE0NDE2LmlhbS5nc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNjc0NTE3NTUwLCJpYXQiOjE2NzQ1MTM5NTAsImRpc3RleHQiOnsiYWNjIjoiVFhwR1ExTlRSazloZWtVeFkybHdTUT09IiwiY3VzIjoiYkhOaGJHUmhjbkpwWVdkaCIsImlkIjoiOTAwODM4MjUifX0.jXL2uPV2007t-DG5jXtYF1M4k-ECcxEXOjJwS5xkys77ijlegQXHcY57IPmcR9Sntzi3nfVIZHt2UbuemxKbXE8bM-GRQXcTIWyPHdOW7BGRqpPDSC1N9Yvbzntca67sIueq1y1E10v4GTNa8Td5WiMg_kA8cdFg_n9sNujgLMt1JCVFJFIlRAeAYhw1Y-boXRDBuqc502tGYz5_aIliMcuGjWruowDVbL6u8dkEsPrnQKgXDDn9j2edJ1dECkTWWA6ITe29RdA9tyxnJPWFe_hW_VvbqjgAplJbCmXWJQZnpXNSQ2OJjs3Uso2rmOGkPZBz21Oml8lTrZe78uxrqg' 
        }
    };

    axios(config).then(function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Lo que no sé cómo hacer, es como puedo guardar el token que tengo en la variable resp y este sacarlo de esta función y poderlo utilizar en otra función diferente.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Puedes guárdalo en local storage de tu navegador, o también como cookies pero comúnmente se usa local storage

Comment: Daniel, gracias su comentario, pero en este caso estoy consumiendo la función desde el back con node.js

Lo que no se es como poner ::

 const resp = JSON.stringify(response.data.response) // quiero almacenar este token y poderlo utilizar en cualquier otra función
        console.log(resp); 

Quede como una variable global que la pueda utilizar desde cualquiera otra función

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el paquete de [node-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache) para almacenar el token y luego llamarlo.

```
const NodeCache = require( "node-cache" );
const cache = new NodeCache();

const token = 'myToken&123';

// Almacenamos el token
cache.set( 'token', token, 0 );

// Obtenemos el token
const getToken = cache.get( 'token' );
```

Comment: muchas gracias, esta solución me sirvió para lo que quería hacer, muchas gracias.